# How to save a file in sql server database using Ext.Net fileuploadfield?

Tags: c#, sql-server, extjs, linq-to-sql, ext.net

I have a basic fileupload button like this

```
<ext:FileUploadField ID="upload1" runat="server" ButtonOnly="true" Icon="Attach">
                </ext:FileUploadField>
```

I want to save the uploaded file in the database using codebehind:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object s, DirectEventArgs e)
{
   // the save file code goes here  
}
```

I have a sql server table with columns **AttachmentUrl**-*varchar(200)* and, **AttachmentName**-*varchar(100)*. I am trying to get the file path, but they say due to browser security reason ext.net doesnot allow this. How can I solve this. Please help. Right now I am using linq but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please refer [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246) link . Hope it will help you

Comment: yes its helpful. I uploaded the file in a folder and saved that folder url in the database but, do you know how can I use GUID to avoid uploading same file or filename. I am stuck.